# error message: The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm a newbie - and am sure it will be obvious.
I found someone with the identical problem on the forums, but it was not resolved.
I got my key today.
I setup an allowed referrer (star.pathsofgrowth.org/star)
I copied the code for map-simple.html and added my API Key and changed the longitude, Latitude coordinates.
The file is http://pathsofgrowth.org/Maps/PhoenixMeditationMap.html.
A map starts to show, then is covered up and above message (and a little more about obtaining a key) is presented.    Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The URL (pathsofgrowth.org) does not match the referrer you quote in the question (star.pathsofgrowth.org) so it wouldn't be allowed. Referrers need to use wildcards, including a final `/*` to match any file/folder within the final specified folder.

To match a URL of http://pathsofgrowth.org/Maps/PhoenixMeditationMap.html your referrer needs to be

```
pathsofgrowth.org/*
```

If you can *also* get to your maps with a subdomain like star or www, you also need to *add* that into your list of allowed referrers:

```
*.pathsofgrowth.org/*
```

You can go as far down the heirarchy as you need, but don't end up with a single file. It needs to be a folder specification:

```
pathsofgrowth.org/Maps/*
```

The Javascript which does the validation is case-sensitive, so if you are running a Windows webserver which is not case-sensitive when serving URLs, you also need to cater for the most common substitutions (all lower-case for a start).

Comment: [It looks like it works now, so you have probably fixed it. This answer is for others to find! But if it's right, do tick the tick to accept it.]